# What is a good algorithm for saving a file periodically and ensuring there's a backup file as well

Tags: algorithm, file, backup

One of our processes(Writer) will be creating a file routinely. Given that Other processes(let's call them readers) will be reading this file at different times, the following questions arise.

a) when the Writer is writing to the file, at the same time the Reader(independent of Writer) doesn't read an incomplete version of the same file. ?
b) should we create a backup file (file.bin~) ? What happens at the instant we are renaming our old file(file.bin) to the backup file (file.bin~) and creating new file (file.bin)?

This is somewhat similar to a backup program that backs up a file while someone is saving a file with an editor.

SUMMARY : while all the file saving and backup file creation are going on, How do you ensure that the Reader program never gets an incomplete file (otherway put, how do you ensure that the Reader program always gets a complete file ?)

Thank you,

Comment: 1. Lock them so you can't read and write at the same time. 2. Rename the old file temporarily so you can rollback if  the writer fails to write.

Answer (score 0):

1. Find a way to let the readers know that the writer is writing, so they can stop reading. (Or alternatively make the writer wait for the readers to finish)
2. Make the writer write the data to a new file (file_new.bin)
3. Copy/move the old file (file.bin) to a new location (file_old.bin)
4. Replace the old file (file.bin) with the new file (file_new.bin)
5. You might consider keeping the old version (file_old.bin) for a simple backup (or alternatively send it to a separate folder(or server) with datestamp etc. for more advanced backup) or simply delete it to save storage